# Difference in means between two dependent variables over multiple year

Tags: time-series, mean, differences

I am trying to figure out the correct way to perform this analysis.

My data consists of multiple companies over a 8-year period. 
The companies are always the same through this period.

For each company, two rates are calculated each year that are dependent.
I would like to compare the averages of these two rates over the years to find out whether or not they, on average, match.

So for each year, the averages for both rates would be calculated from that year's rates and for each year the difference would be tested.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: In what sense are the two rates dependent? Eg, are they different numerators over the same denominator?

Comment: That is actually a good question which got me thinking: are they?. Both rates are calculated from companies financial information but they do not use the same exact information. One uses sales and one uses net income + dividends + equity information. Am I correct to assume that they are then in fact not dependent? My first thought was they are are dependent since they are both calculated from same company's data but I guess they are not.

Comment: Well if you control for company or include random effects for companies, then the non-independence of the data due to coming from the same company will be addressed.